# Secondary Navigation Below Hompage Banner

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to code a secondary navigation under the first homepage banner with a fixed header that sticks upon scroll.

Example On:  www.neffassociates.com (please scroll down slightly)

Comment: css [position: sticky](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Listen window scroll event
- Check if your navbar is the top edge

I made an example for you, It will give an idea
[pen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PLjeJW)

Example from codepen:

```
var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar').getBoundingClientRect();
var isSticky = false;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var s = window.scrollY;
  var navbarCls = 'navbar--fixed';
  var nextEl = document.querySelector('.navbar + *');
  if (s >= navbar.top) {
    nextEl.style.paddingTop = navbar.height + "px";
    document.body.classList.add(navbarCls);
    isSticky = true;
  } else if(s < navbar.top && isSticky) {
    document.body.classList.remove(navbarCls);
    isSticky = false;
    nextEl.removeAttribute('style');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you!  How do I keep the navbar in front of all other elements on scroll?  It hides behind sections as I scroll?  Thanks man!

Comment: You are welcome. Try to change the `z-index` of your navbar. It should solve the hiding issue

Comment: Great.  Adjusting z-index worked.  Another quick question:  When I scroll down my page it triggers the navbar position too quick... in other words, I'd like for it to be a smooth transition into a fixed head when the element reaches the top of the page.  Right now it jumps to being a fix border on scroll with a good 3" gap on screen.  How could I code this to become a fixed header as scroll reaches top of screen?

Comment: Is there a way to add some code where the navbar doesn't become fixed until the page reaches the top?  So the transition is just natural not "jumped" to the top when triggered?  Sorry if I am not making sense.  Trying lol

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize the jumping issue my bad.. Updated the answer.
The problem is if you make an element `position:fixed;` that element will not occupy a `height/width` on the page. To solve this, we had to add `padding-top` to next element after navbar. The `padding-top` value should be as much as height of navbar. Then it will be natural transition.